# Enlarge and reposition arrows for slick slider

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slick.js

[image]

I am putting together a slide presentation using a jquery plugin called 'slick' (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) using django and a bootstrap 3 template. I've got a basic carousel working  using a django template that looks like:

```
 <div class="intro-header">  
    <div class="container">


        <div class="your-class">
            <div><IMG img width="100%" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSj2c33fdt1ugB8VBuE5V37wnmPoxWMknX9JnGycNiH2yr3BpDKVA"></div>
            <div><IMG width="100%" src="{% static 'img/slides/1.jpg' %}"></div>
          </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

</div>
<!-- /.intro-header -->
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to enlarge the arrows and even move them on to the left and right edges of each slide.

The CSS in the head is:

```
<style>
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
    color:red !important;

}
.your-class{
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
</style>
```

edit:

following your directions I've found:

```
.slick-prev, .slick-next {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: medium none;
color: transparent;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
font-size: 0px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 0;
margin-top: -10px;
outline: medium none;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: 20px;
}
```

In the slick-theme.css. I tried changing height but that corresponds to vertical positioning of the arrow on the page. Do these elements look like they control position and size, or is there something else to look for?

Answer (score 4):

In slick-theme.css there is the below style. Editing the font-size will change the size of the button. This is because the content for the .slick-prev:before and .slick-next:before is set in the same file.

```
.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before
{
  font-family: 'slick';
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;

  opacity: .75;
  color: white;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use debugg tools so you will be able to see what class is called for arrow positioning and size..When you accure the class its easy to override it.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot after clicking on the right arrow in firebug. Do I look in the style tab for those classes? Sorry, not experienced with CSS debugging.

Comment: upper left on the toolbar menu you will see icon that looks like arrow and rectangle click on it and than click on the arrow on the screen.The arrow element should be selected and on the style tab you can debugg it..

Answer (score 0):

Find the element via google developer tools or inspector to where the arrows are coming from. Grab that selector and redefine the styles!

```
.slick-prev { 
    left: 100px; // download the themes actual stylesheet so you can style easier on your host
    top: 10px !important; // add important if you need to override 
    height: 6000px; // your custom
}
```

Comment: Loyd, thanks for looking at this. sorry I'm not CSS savvy. Could you explain more about how to "Grab that selector and redefine the styles!"